# Customization Orbeon Builder first dialog

Tags: forms, orbeon

I want to customize the first dialog, which shows up, when I launch Form Builder. By default there are four fields: appName, formName, title and desription. I want to disable title field, and add some fields. How can I do it? Which files I have to edit? I know that, there is some file called dialog-form-settings.xml, but I don't know where is it.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the file you're referring to: [`dialog-form-settings.xbl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/fb/dialog-form-settings/dialog-form-settings.xbl). This file is in `orbeon-resources-private.jar` and if you override it, you can place your version in `WEB-INF/resources`, following the same path (i.e. `WEB-INF/resources/xbl/fb/dialog-form-settings/dialog-form-settings.xbl`).